# Call assets folder from css in Android

Tags: android, css, assets

I am writing a css in Android. I want to use HelveticaNeue_Light font. This font is in the assets folder. What I am doing is

```
body ="<HEAD><STYLE>.class1{color:gray;text-align:left;@font-face {font-family: HelveticaNeue_Light;src: url('file:///android_asset/HelveticaNeue_Light.ttf');};font-size:17px;}</STYLE><‌​/HEAD><BODY><div class=\"class1\"><P>"+TEXT+ '</P></BODY>"
```

but it didn't work. what to do?

Answer (score 3):

because u should separate selectors

```
  <STYLE>
    .class1{color:gray;text-align:left;font-size:17px;}
    @font-face {font-family: HelveticaNeue_Light;src: url('file:///android_asset/HelveticaNeue_Light.ttf');}
  </STYLE>
```

Comment: _body = "<HEAD><STYLE>@font-face {font-family: HelveticaNeue_Light;src:url('/assets/HelveticaNeue_Light.ttf');}.class1{color:gray;text-align:left;font-family:HelveticaNeue_Light;font-size:17px;}</STYLE></HEAD><BODY><div class=\"class1\"><P>" + TEXT + " </P></BODY>";  --- didint work!

Comment: You might want to add a link to some documentation http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule

Comment: check your font path, and try to add quotes for the font name.

Comment: _body = "<HEAD><STYLE>@font-face {font-family:\"HelveticaNeue_Light\";src:url(\"file:///android_asset/HelveticaNeue_Light.ttf\");}.class1{color:gray;text-align:left;font-family:\"HelveticaNeue_Light\";font-size:17px;}</STYLE></HEAD><BODY><div class=\"class1\"><P>"+ text+ " </P></BODY>"; -- not working

Comment: r y sure about your path?
src:url(\"file:///android_asset/HelveticaNe‌​ue_Light.ttf\")

Comment: it is the assets path in android. isn't?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it in my css:

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url("fonts/UniversLTStd-BoldObl.ttf")
}
```

Both my fonts and css are under the assets folder.